# Node router can't get data from Sequelize using async await

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, sequelize.js

Using `Sequelize`for the first time I'm trying this code in my Node router:

```
router.get('/get-users', async (req, res, next) => {
  const data = await users.getAll()
  console.log('users in router:', data);
  res.send(data)
});
```

And this is the sequlize code:

```
const users = {
  getAll () {
    sequelize
      .query('SELECT * FROM users', { model: User })
      .then(users => {
        console.log('users in database:', users);
        return users;
      })
  }
};
```

The log statement in Sequelize code is getting me the right data but the log statement in router gets undefined.

It's probably async await problem but can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to return the promise in the getAll(). Await is just a wrapper for a then() call of a promise but since you are not returning a promise the await is not waiting for the promise.

```
  getAll () {
    return sequelize
      .query('SELECT * FROM users', { model: User })
      .then(users => {
        console.log('users in database:', users);
        return users;
    })
  }
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Yes I forgot to the part of returning a promise.